# Spark: How to save the output (saveAsTextFile) to files with equal size?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following code, trying to output the RDD to 1000 files with **equal file size**. However, I still got only 70 output files, and the file size are very different (range from 50M to 2G). Is there any additional step I need to do in order to make the output files having equal size? Thank you!

```
val myRDD = input.flatMap { t => ??? }
                 .reduceByKey { (t1, t2) => ??? ; t3 }
                 .sortBy(-_._2.size)
                 .repartition(1000)
                 .map(t => (t._1 + "_" + t._2.size, t._2.toString))

myRDD.saveAsTextFile("myOutput", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RangePartitioner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L92) to create equal sized partitions and then save tham as text file.

Example taken from [there](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201402.mbox/%3C254FB914-9106-4F00-996B-A0BC3AAD8549@gmail.com%3E):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner;
var file=sc.textFile("<my local path>")    
var partitionedFile=file.map(x=>(x,1))
var data= partitionedFile.partitionBy(new RangePartitioner(3, partitionedFile))
data.glom().collect()(0).length
data.glom().collect()(1).length
data.glom().collect()(2).length
```

In your case, instead of collecting and checking length, running `saveAsTextFile()` should be enough.

Comment: Would u mind sharing an example on how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: I have little time now, so I found a ready solution, please verify if it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straighforward, all you need to do is use repartition(1000)
 and you file sizes will be equal and exactly 1000

Your code modified :

```
val myRDD = input.flatMap { t => ??? }
                 .reduceByKey { (t1, t2) => ??? ; t3 }
                 .sortBy(-_._2.size)
                 .repartition(1000)
                 .map(t => (t._1 + "_" + t._2.size, t._2.toString)).repartition(1000)

myRDD.saveAsTextFile("myOutput", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the following answer will solve your purpose

val myRDD = input.flatMap { t => ??? }
                 .reduceByKey { (t1, t2) => ??? ; t3 }
                 .sortBy(-_._2.size)
                 .repartition(1000)
                 .map(t => (t._1 + "_" + t._2.size, t._2.toString))

myRDD.repartition(1000).saveAsTextFile("myOutput", classOf[GzipCodec])

One thing to note that original rdd will have it's existance even after this because it is immutable 

or even you can use coalesce(1000) if you want to set max partitions to set
```